# Conditional PHP styling based on variable value

Tags: php

I have some PHP code which executes and selects 10 rows from a SQL table. One column called `result` can hold the value of won, or loss.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<div class = 'logrow'> <img src ='". $row["url"] ."'</img> <p class = 'logtext'>". $row["name"] ." bet $". $row["amount"] ." with a ".  $row["chance"] ."% chance and ". $row["result"] .". </p> </div>";
    }
```

How could I do something which would echo the values from each row as above but to echo a different statement for each row where the value of `result` is loss. For example to add an inline styling for the background colour.

So for example, say I have 10 rows found - 9 of these have `$row["result"]`as won, so they should be echoed as above. But 1 row has the value of `$row["result"]` as loss, a different echo should be applied. Perhaps with an inline style, or maybe with a variable inserted which hold this style.

I know this is very specific and may not be clear so thanks in advance.

Comment: just use an if... `if($row["result"] == 'won')`. Then you echo something different in the if than in the else...

Comment: Will this work for every row, if there are more than one? I always though while() had to be used here. If not, can you make this an answer so i can mark the question as answered. TIA

Comment: @Aba's answer is simple and efficient :) You can put the css in your actual css file...

Comment: Thanks random :) Aba's answer is definately awesome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the value in $row["result"] (won/loss) create a class and use it in the echo

```
css:
    .won{background-color::blue}
    .loss{background-color::red}

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<div class = 'logrow ". $row["result"] ."'> <img src ='". $row["url"] ."'</img> <p class = 'logtext'>". $row["name"] ." bet $". $row["amount"] ." with a ".  $row["chance"] ."% chance and ". $row["result"] .". </p> </div>";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this by changing class names.

```
<?php 
 $status = $row['result'];
 $classname = 'won';
 if($status == 0){
   $classname = 'fail';
 }
?>
<div class = 'logrow <?php echo $classname ?> '> <img src ='". $row["url"] ."'</img> <p class = 'logtext'>". $row["name"] ." bet $". $row["amount"] ." with a ".  $row["chance"] ."% chance and ". $row["result"] .". </p> </div>";
```

Now define classes for `won` and `fail` under style sheet.

```
<style type="text/css">
.won{ color: green; }
.fail{ color: red; }
</style>
```